# sockets tcp example in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm looking for a good example of a simple TCP server/client that can deliver messages from one client to another.  I have looked at many examples, but I can only find really complex ones, or one's where only one client talks to the server and back, and not to each other.

Comment: It would be best if you could try something simple, then post more specific questions once you've tried something.

Answer (score 3):

See selectserver.c at http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html. Clients are defined earlier on the page and server seems pretty easy to expand.

Comment: That one is good but it doesn't have an example of 2 clients communicating to each other.

Comment: @JonBlake That's because it's impossible with TCP sockets.  You need one side to create a listening socket ("be a server") and the other to connect ("be a client").  For connectionless transport look into UDP.  Read section 2 in Beej's guide for more details.